# Instagram with NodeJS is throwing 404 error

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

```
var express = require('express'),
  instagram = require('instagram-node').instagram(),
  app = express();

  instagram.use({access_token: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'});

instagram.use({
  client_id: 'my_client_id',
  client_secret: 'my_client_secret'  
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  instagram.use({ access_token: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' });
  instagram.media_popular(function(err, medias, remaining, limit) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err.body);
    }      
    else  {
       console.log(medias);
       res.render('pages/index', { grams: medias });
    }
  });
});
app.listen(8888,function(){
  console.log("listening port 8888")
});
```

So, this is my code. When I'm hitting the http://localhost:8888, I'm getting the following page

[image]

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why am I not logged in when I get the 404 page?

Comment: Are you getting inside the if error statement? If so, I'd recommend logging out the error and posting that with your question

Comment: Yes, the flow is going into the if(err) staement I logged it and I got the html code of 404 page of instagram

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the body property on the error that is the html? Could you post what err is in the question?

Comment: Please find the **err.body** log [here](http://pastebin.com/u8bFEDkA)

Comment: Can you post the **full** output of what err is? Not just err.body

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/cXm5pEaQ

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is the problem but as an workaround  you can use requestjs to send GET request using this

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

url. You will get the same data. Might not be a clear solution but I know that work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

check your access token while passing through the URL. I got this page when my URL was not correct.

You can use this code after getting access token for getting user data from instagram.

```
exports.getUserData = function(req, res) {
    var outputJSON = "";
    var requestUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=YOUR ACCESS TOKEN HERE';
    request.get({ url: requestUrl, json: true }, function(err, response, accessToken) {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            outputJSON = { 'status': 'failure', 'messageId': 403, 'message': err };
        } else {
            outputJSON = { 'status': 'success', 'messageId': 200, 'data': response.body }
                //console.log('response',response.body);
        }
        res.jsonp(outputJSON);
    });
}
```